# facebook api email permissions

Tags: facebook, email, permissions

I am using scope-email in order to get users email on facebook api. How is it possible to gain users email by requesting basic info and ask for email permissions in one easy step? So far I have managed to request basic info and then ask for email permissions in 2 steps.
http://apps.facebook.com/slotomania/?fb_source=search&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fslotomania%2F%3Ffb_source%3Dsearch&src=yb3_22_S-C_C_A2-A11_Feb14_Sr&ref=ts&fref=ts

Comment: email has been asked for in the first “page” of the login dialog for quite a while now …

Comment: i found this is the facebook bug. If the facebook email contain "_" or ".", then this issue will happen. You can try to change your facebook primary email and test again.

Comment: Can you provide any documentation of this 'bug'?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you go into your developer page and click on the app settings you can edit permissions the app requests.  If you click in the User & Friend Permissions field and start typing email, you can tell your app to request email permissions.  If you then click on the "Preview Login Dialogue" you will see it asks for exactly what you linked to.

[image: Screenshot]