# Obtain user email from Facebook SessionLoginSample iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to get the user's email address from Facebook's SessionLoginSample app. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I believe this is the correct area where I would obtain the email address. Is there any direction you can give me as to what part of this will assist my effort to return a simple email? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
- (void)updateView {
    // get the app delegate, so that we can reference the session property
    SLAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {        
        // valid account UI is shown whenever the session is open
        [self.buttonLoginLogout setTitle:@"Log out" forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
        [self.textNoteOrLink setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=%@",
                                 appDelegate.session.accessTokenData.accessToken]];

//GET THE USER'S EMAIL ADDRESS HERE        
NSString *emailAddress= [user objectForKey:@"email"];         

        self.labelFirstName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email: %@", emailAddress];

    } else {        
        // login-needed account UI is shown whenever the session is closed
        [self.buttonLoginLogout setTitle:@"Log in" forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
        [self.textNoteOrLink setText:@"Login to create a link to fetch account data"];        
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you setup the permissions?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481784/facebook-api-email-permissions

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure you have asked a user for permission to access his email address. Here is the link to documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/

**Example**

Make an array with permissionsns

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"email",nil];
```

And then add permissions to openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions: method like this:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
             allowLoginUI:YES
        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                            FBSessionState status,
                            NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                           message:error.localizedDescription
                                           delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alert show];

            } 
        }];
```

This example is using Facebook SDK for iOS