# Enabling email permission acquiring when making a Facebook login on my website

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get Name and Email information about the user that connects to my site with Facebook Login.

I've looked in this article and i've made the written step:

[facebook api email permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481784/facebook-api-email-permissions)

Then i went to my Application section in my profile and i've made a call to the Graph API specifying my email address too, then i went back to my website and i've made a login:

My name and my email address were displayed.

But if another user goes to the same webpage and makes the login, only his/her name is being displayed and not his/her email address.

Here i attach you the code that i'm using to

```
include ('php-sdk/facebook.php');

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = FB_APP_ID;
$config['secret'] = FB_APP_SECRET;
$config['fileUpload'] = false;
$config['cookie'] = true;

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user_id) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile["name"];
        echo "Email: " . $user_profile["email"];
        $logout_url = $facebook->destroySession();
        echo '<a href="'.$logout_url.'">Effettua il logout</a>';
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) { // try
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email'));
        echo 'Please <a href="'.$login_url.'">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    } /*catch*/
} else {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo 'Please <a href="'.$login_url.'">login.</a>';
}
```

Which points am i missing?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try it with different users?

Comment: In your `else` branch, you are not asking for the permission …

Comment: So stupid. Thanks. Actually it's not working with the user_location. CBroe do you have any suggestion?